# How to change timestamps in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, timestamp

i want to change the timestamp to current time but it doesn't work. What should i do?

```
 $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [useCurrent()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#column-modifiers) method:

```php
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
```

Comment: still the same. it doesn't change to current time in phpmyadmin. I use laravel 5.8

Comment: @Loka is there some error message? and what's your mysql version?

Comment: or @Loka it may be changing to current UTC time. try to change your timezone from .env.

Comment: @Ashish it's worked. Thanks. And Thanks tsaikoga for helping